# How to store directory files listing into an array?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to store the files listing into an array and then loop through the array again. 
Below is what I get when I run `ls -ls` command from the console.

```
total 40
36 -rwxrwxr-x 1 amit amit 36720 2012-03-31 12:19 1.txt
4 -rwxrwxr-x 1 amit amit  1318 2012-03-31 14:49 2.txt
```

The following bash script I've written to store the above data into a bash array.

```
i=0
ls -ls | while read line
do
    array[ $i ]="$line"        
    (( i++ ))
done
```

But when I `echo $array`, I get nothing!

FYI, I run the script this way: `./bashscript.sh`

Comment: bash run pipeline in sub shell, so your assignment to array is only available in do .. done.

Comment: I would suggest that the question here is really "How to iterate over a directory list"?  **Arrays are NOT universally supported in shell scripts**.

Comment: And even if you have a shell with arrays, you don't want or need to keep the file names in memory just to loop over them one by one. An array is useful if you want to compare every file to every other file, for example, but to just loop over files, use a regular `for file in *` or whatever, and don't squander memory on keeping a copy of the information the shell is perfectly capable of producing at any time.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try with:

```
#! /bin/bash

i=0
while read line
do
    array[ $i ]="$line"        
    (( i++ ))
done < <(ls -ls)

echo ${array[1]}
```

In your version, the `while` runs in a subshell, the environment variables you modify in the loop are not visible outside it.

(Do keep in mind that parsing the output of `ls` is generally [not a good idea at all](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).)

Comment: `<(ls -ls)` Would you mind explaining that notation? I don't understand why it isn't simply `ls -ls`

Comment: clean files list: ls -1

Comment: if parsing `ls` output is bad (it is bad), why would you suggest doing it in an answer? People will miss the disclaimer and be left with the idea that parsing through `ls` is just fine.

Comment: Any approach with "while read line" would be incorrect since \n is a valid filename character too.

Comment: Mat - like @imagineerThat requested and so am i doing again.. would you give few minutes to explain the functioning of `<(ls -ls)`.

Answer (score 145):

I'd use

```
files=(*)
```

And then if you need data about the file, such as size, use the [`stat`](http://man.cx/stat) command on each file.

Comment: Fantastic! Even works with directory names prepended, to get files from more than one directory (ie `files_in_dirs=(dir/* other_dir/*)`. Very useful, thanks.

Comment: And then to list all elements in this files array:  `echo ${files[@]}` or use that in for loop

Comment: On macs this seems to not work when files contain spaces (which is unfortunately frequent).  There may be a work around.  If anyone can find what this syntax is doing in the bash documentation, that may help us figure out a solution to this issue.

Comment: empty dirs will cause unpredictable errors without "shopt -s nullglob".

Comment: @David, there is not problem with files with spaces: they will be stored in the array properly as a single element. It is extracting the file from the array as a single unit that requires care: `for filename in "${files[@]}"` -- where the quotes are crucial. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12316565/7552) for examples.

Comment: @glennjackman hey `for filename in "${files[@]}"`, it treat all elements into one unit. at least in win7...

Comment: Where do you have bash on win7?

Comment: Can this be used to get (only files) or (everything except symlinks).

Comment: On Macs and elsewhere, this works fine if you then also quote your variable inside the loop. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @RatDon Look into `find` options; it can do all that and lots more.

Comment: what's the order of the files being stored in array, it feels like a plain `ls` output order. But I failed to find this in any documentation to confirm my guess.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a variant that lets you use a regex pattern for initial filtering, change the regex to be get the filtering you desire.

```
files=($(find -E . -type f -regex "^.*$"))
for item in ${files[*]}
do
  printf "   %s\n" $item
done
```

Comment: Word-splitting applies to the expansion of the command substitution, so each space creates a separate array element. If there is a file called `foo bar.txt`, `item` will be set to `foo`, then `bar.txt`.

Comment: ah yes, after reading your comment I only focused on the regex.. nice catch.

Comment: So how would you catch spaces?

Comment: This is horribly broken. [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you:

```
OIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; array=($(ls -ls)); IFS=$OIFS; echo "${array[1]}"
```

Comment: Or simpler: `IFS=$'\n' array=($(ls -ls))`

Comment: @Guss Simpler, yes.  Correct, no.  The use of `OIFS` here involves restoring the internal field separator after you've change it temporarily.  Failing to do that is likely to cause you a lot of subsequent problems!

Comment: Ok, @BuvinJ, granted. Then how about `(IFS=$'\n' array=($(ls -ls)))` ? the `$IFS` change is now limited to a subshell and won't propagate further. Still simpler ;-)

Comment: Great idea.  I'm not sure about the syntax though.  I believe you mean `$(IFS='\n'; array=($(ls -ls)))` would make it run in a subshell, but then your `array` variable is also lost upon return to the outer script!  Each way I think about solving this, ends up being at least as long / complicated as the original approach from @potong.  And his way is, in the fact, the "canonical" approach to messing with IFS.

Answer (score 3):

Running any shell command inside `$(...)` will help to store the output in a variable. So using that we can convert the files to array with `IFS`.

```
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< $(ls /path/to/dir)
```

Comment: No handling of whitespaces here (at least in bash).
`touch a b 'c d'; IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< $(ls); echo ${#array[@]}` prints 1, should be 3.

Answer (score 1):

You may be tempted to use `(*)` but what if a directory contains the `*` character? It's very difficult to handle special characters in filenames correctly.

You can use `ls -ls`. However, it fails to handle newline characters.

```
# Store la -ls as an array
readarray -t files <<< $(ls -ls)
for (( i=1; i<${#files[@]}; i++ ))
{
    # Convert current line to an array
    line=(${files[$i]})
    # Get the filename, joining it together any spaces
    fileName=${line[@]:9}
    echo $fileName
}
```

If all you want is the file name, then just use `ls`:

```
for fileName in $(ls); do
    echo $fileName
done
```

See this [article](https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) or this [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9499/289953) post for more information about some of the difficulties of dealing with special characters in file names.

Comment: No, it's not hard at all. Just [don't use `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) you'll be fine.

Comment: @tripleee if I quote properly using `*`, then it displays newline characters in the filename. Therefore, it offers no advantages over `ls`, but if used incorrectly `*` can be dangerous. Using `ls` might not be perfect, but what would you suggest as a better way?

Comment: If a name contains a newline character, storing and displaying that newline character is exactly the right thing to do, isn't it? The first link in my comment contains extensive documentation for why you should basically never use `ls` in scripts, and what to use instead.

Comment: @tripleee I already read that article before I posted and I disagree with it. I'm sure there are times when `ls` is definitely the wrong tool for the job, but to assume that it never is absurd, especially, when the article does not present good alternatives. It says not to use `ls` and to use `(*)` instead, but provides no good reason to. Using `(*)' can be dangerous if not quoted and still has the same problems `ls` does.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your argument, but you are not helping. Can you provide an example where `ls` works and `(*)` does not, or ends up being much more complex?

Answer (score 1):

### My two cents

The asker wanted to parse output of `ls -ls`

> Below is what I get when I run `ls -ls` command from the console.
>
> ```
> total 40
> 36 -rwxrwxr-x 1 amit amit 36720 2012-03-31 12:19 1.txt
> 4 -rwxrwxr-x 1 amit amit  1318 2012-03-31 14:49 2.txt
> ```

But there are few answer addressing **this** parsing operation.

#### `ls`'s output

Before trying to parse something, we have to ensure command output is *consistant*, *stable* and *easy to parse as possible*

- In order to ensure output wont be altered by some `alias` you may prefer to specify full path of command: `/bin/ls`.
- Avoid variations of output due to locales, prefix your command by `LANG=C LC_ALL=C`
- Use `--time-style` command switch to use UNIX EPOCH more easier to parse time infos.
- Use `-b` switch for holding *special characters*

So we will prefer

```
LANG=C LC_ALL=C /bin/ls -lsb --time-style='+%s.%N'
```

to just

```
ls -ls
```

#### Full bash sample

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a bydate=() bysize=() byname=() details=()
declare -i cnt=0 vtotblk=0 totblk
{
    read -r _ totblk # ignore 1st line
    while read -r blk perm lnk usr grp sze date file;do
        byname[cnt]="${file//\\ / }"
        details[cnt]="$blk $perm $lnk $usr $grp $sze $date"
        bysize[sze]+="$cnt "
        bydate[${date/.}]+="$cnt "
        cnt+=1 vtotblk+=blk
    done
} < <(LANG=C LC_ALL=C /bin/ls -lsb --time-style='+%s.%N')
```

From there, you could easily sort by *dates*, *sizes* of *names* (sorted by `ls` command).

```
echo "Path '$PWD': Total: $vtotblk, sorted by dates"
for dte in ${!bydate[@]};do
    printf -v msec %.3f .${dte: -9}
    for idx in ${bydate[dte]};do
        read -r blk perm lnk usr grp sze date <<<"${details[idx]}"
        printf ' %11d %(%a %d %b %T)T%s %s\n' \
               $sze "${date%.*}" ${msec#0} "${byname[idx]}"
    done
done

echo "Path '$PWD': Total: $vtotblk, sorted by sizes"
for sze in ${!bysize[@]};do
    for idx in ${bysize[sze]};do
        read -r blk perm lnk usr grp sze date <<<"${details[idx]}"
        printf -v msec %.3f .${date#*.}
        printf ' %11d %(%a %d %b %T)T%s %s\n' \
               $sze "${date%.*}" ${msec#0} "${byname[idx]}"
    done
done

echo "Path '$PWD': Total: $vtotblk, sorted by names"
for((idx=0;idx<cnt;idx++));{
    read -r blk perm lnk usr grp sze date <<<"${details[idx]}"    
    printf -v msec %.3f .${date#*.}
    printf ' %11d %(%a %d %b %T)T%s %s\n' \
           $sze "${date%.*}" ${msec#0} "${byname[idx]}"
}
```

( Accessory, you could check if total block printed by `ls` match total block by lines:

```
(( vtotblk == totblk )) ||
    echo "WARN: Total blocks: $totblk != Block count: $vtotblk" >&2
```

Of course, this could be inserted **before** first `echo "Path...`;)

Here is an output sample. (Note: there is a filename with a *newline*)

```
Path '/tmp/so': Total: 16, sorted by dates
           0 Sun 04 Sep 10:09:18.221 2.txt
         247 Mon 05 Sep 09:11:50.322 Filename with\nsp\303\251cials characters
          13 Mon 05 Sep 10:12:24.859 1.txt
        1313 Mon 05 Sep 11:01:00.855 parseLs.00
        1913 Thu 08 Sep 08:20:20.836 parseLs
Path '/tmp/so': Total: 16, sorted by sizes
           0 Sun 04 Sep 10:09:18.221 2.txt
          13 Mon 05 Sep 10:12:24.859 1.txt
         247 Mon 05 Sep 09:11:50.322 Filename with\nsp\303\251cials characters
        1313 Mon 05 Sep 11:01:00.855 parseLs.00
        1913 Thu 08 Sep 08:20:20.836 parseLs
Path '/tmp/so': Total: 16, sorted by names
          13 Mon 05 Sep 10:12:24.859 1.txt
           0 Sun 04 Sep 10:09:18.221 2.txt
         247 Mon 05 Sep 09:11:50.322 Filename with\nsp\303\251cials characters
        1913 Thu 08 Sep 08:20:20.836 parseLs
        1313 Mon 05 Sep 11:01:00.855 parseLs.00
```

And if you want to format characters (with care: [there could be some issues](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/56309/15701), if you don't know who create content of *`path`*). But if folder is your, you could:

```
echo "Path '$PWD': Total: $vtotblk, sorted by dates, with special chars"
printf -v spaces '%*s' 37 ''
for dte in ${!bydate[@]};do
    printf -v msec %.3f .${dte: -9}
    for idx in ${bydate[dte]};do
        read -r blk perm lnk usr grp sze date <<<"${details[idx]}"
        printf ' %11d %(%a %d %b %T)T%s %b\n' $sze \
            "${date%.*}" ${msec#0} "${byname[idx]//\\n/\\n$spaces}"
    done
done
```

Could output:

```
Path '/tmp/so': Total: 16, sorted by dates, with special chars
           0 Sun 04 Sep 10:09:18.221 2.txt
         247 Mon 05 Sep 09:11:50.322 Filename with
                                     spécials characters
          13 Mon 05 Sep 10:12:24.859 1.txt
        1313 Mon 05 Sep 11:01:00.855 parseLs.00
        1913 Thu 08 Sep 08:20:20.836 parseLs
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't these 2 code lines, either using scandir or including the dir pull in the declaration line, supposed to work?

```
src_dir="/3T/data/MySQL";
# src_ray=scandir($src_dir);
declare -a src_ray ${src_dir/*.sql}
printf ( $src_ray );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the conversation over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9954738/11944425
the behavior can be wrapped into a convenience function which applies some action to entries of the directory as string values.

```
#!/bin/bash
iterfiles() {
    i=0
    while read filename
    do 
        files[ $i ]="$filename"
        (( i++ ))
    done < <( ls -l )
    for (( idx=0 ; idx<${#files[@]} ; idx++ ))
    do 
        $@ "${files[$idx]}" &
        wait $!
    done
}
```

where `$@` is the complete glob of arguments passed to the function! This lets the function have the utility to take an arbitrary command as a partial function of sorts to operate on the filename:

```
iterfiles head -n 1 | tee -a header_check.out
```

When a script needs to iterate over files, returning an array of them is not possible. The workaround is to define the array outside of the function scope (and possibly `unset` it later) — modifying it inside the function's scope. Then, after the function is called by a script, the array variable becomes available. For instance, the mutation on `files` demonstrates how this could be done.

```
declare -a files # or just `files= ` (nothing)
iterfiles() {
    # ...
    files=...
}
```

Extending the conversation above, [@Jean-BaptistePoittevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13369176/jean-baptiste-poittevin) pointed out a valuable detail.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Adding a section to unset certain variable names that
# may already be active in the shell.
unset i
unset files
unset omit

i=0
omit='^([\n]+)$'
while read file
do
    files[ $i ]="$file"
    (( i++ ))
done < <(ls -l | grep -Pov ${omit} )
```

> Note: This can be tested using `echo ${files[0]}` or `for entry in ${files[@]}; do ... ; done`

Often times, the circumstance could require an absolute path in double quotes, where the file (or ancestor directories) have spaces or unusual characters in the name. `find` is one answer here. The simplest usage might look like the above one, except `done < <(ls -l ... )` is replaced with:

```
done < <(find /path/to/directory ! -path /path/to/directory -type d)
```

Its convenient when you need absolute paths in double quotes as an iterable collection to use a recipe like the one below. When `export` is not used, the shell does not update the environment namespace to include it in the `find` subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DIRECTORY="$PWD" # For example
declare -a files

i=0
while read filename; do 
    files[ $i ]="$filename"
done < <(find $DIRECTORY ! -path $DIRECTORY -type d)

for (( idx=0; idx<${#files[@]}; idx++ )); do

    # Make a templated string for macro script generation
    quoted_path="\"${files[$idx]}\""
    
    if [[ "$(echo $quoted_path | grep some_substring | wc -c)" != "0" ]]; then
        echo "mv $quoted_path /some/other/watched/folder/" >> run_nightly.sh
    fi

done
```

Upon running this, `./run_nightly.sh` will be populated with bulk commands to move a quoted path to `/some/other/watched/folder/`. This kind of scripting pattern will make it possible to supercharge your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
array=($(ls -l path/to/directory | awk '{print $9}'))
```

You may need to adjust the 9 to get the correct parsing

Answer (score -1):

simply you can use this below for loop (do not forget to quote to handle filenames with spaces)

```
declare -a arr
arr=()
for file in "*.txt"
do
    arr=(${arr[*]} "$file")
done
```

Run

```
for file in ${arr[*]}
do
    echo "<$file>"
done
```

to test.

Comment: Improved a bit but "shellcheck" still complains about potential errors. bash syntax is historical trashheap.

Comment: Wrong on at least two counts.  Firstly, `for file in "*.txt"` can be replaced by a non-loop `file=*.txt`, since the name isn't in a globbing context there.  It's certainly not what was asked for.  And both uses of `${arr[*]}` should be `"${arr[@]}"` so that they don't undergo word splitting.