# Bash script - how to fill array?

Tags: arrays, bash, ls

Let's say I have this directory structure:

```
DIRECTORY:

.........a

.........b

.........c

.........d
```

What I want to do is: I want to store elements of a directory in an array

something like :  `array = ls /home/user/DIRECTORY`

so that `array[0]` contains name of first file (that is 'a')

`array[1] == 'b'`  etc.

Thanks for help

Comment: This may be helpful: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html. Use a `for` loop to iterate through the return values of `ls`.

Comment: This may be helpful too; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954680/how-to-store-directory-files-listing-into-an-array

Comment: Do all those dots in the directory listing mean anything?

Comment: no. dots are only showing 'subelements'

Comment: This may be helpful too: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-arrays-in-bash-script

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't simply do `array = ls /home/user/DIRECTORY`, because - even with proper syntax - it wouldn't give you an array, but a string that you would have to parse, and [Parsing `ls` is punishable by law](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You can, however, use built-in Bash constructs to achieve what you want :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly YOUR_DIR="/home/daniel"

if [[ ! -d $YOUR_DIR ]]; then
    echo >&2 "$YOUR_DIR does not exist or is not a directory"
    exit 1
fi

OLD_PWD=$PWD
cd "$YOUR_DIR"

i=0
for file in *
do
    if [[ -f $file ]]; then
        array[$i]=$file
        i=$(($i+1))
    fi
done

cd "$OLD_PWD"
exit 0
```

This small script saves the names of all the regular files (which means no directories, links, sockets, and such) that can be found in `$YOUR_DIR` to the array called `array`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works, but only for files.
I would also like to store name of a directory to array (if there is any)

Comment: Just modify the `if` in the loop according to your needs, then.

Answer (score 7):

Option 1, a manual loop:

```
dirtolist=/home/user/DIRECTORY
shopt -s nullglob    # In case there aren't any files
contentsarray=()
for filepath in "$dirtolist"/*; do
    contentsarray+=("$(basename "$filepath")")
done
shopt -u nullglob    # Optional, restore default behavior for unmatched file globs
```

Option 2, using bash array trickery:

```
dirtolist=/home/user/DIRECTORY
shopt -s nullglob
contentspaths=("$dirtolist"/*)   # This makes an array of paths to the files
contentsarray=("${contentpaths[@]##*/}")  # This strips off the path portions, leaving just the filenames
shopt -u nullglob    # Optional, restore default behavior for unmatched file globs
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array=($(ls /home/user/DIRECTORY))
```

Then

```
echo ${array[0]}
```

will equal to the first file in that directory.